# Force compiler to emit an error when not all implementations are covered in "when" statement

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

Maybe this is an absurd question. I have a method that receives a `Command` (sealed class) and returns `Unit` and I want the compiler to crash whether all the `when` branches have not been implemented:

```
sealed class Command
class FirstCommand : Command()
class SecondCommand: Command()

fun handle(cmd: Command) {
  when(cmd) {
    is FirstCommand -> //whatever     
  }
}
```

The code above is ok, but I would like it not to compile.

When method returns anything different from `Unit`, it does not compile:

```
fun handle(cmd: Command) : Any {
  when(cmd) { //error, when must be exhaustive and requires all branches
    is FirstCommand -> //whatever     
  }
}
```

I want that behavior but returning nothing (`Unit`). I understand why that happens, but I'm wondering if there is any way I can change my code to achieve what I want. I need cover all the `Command` implementations without forget anyone that may be added later.

Comment: A point about terminology: you don't want the compiler to crash! You just want it to emit an error message. The compiler would only crash if it itself had a bug.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Absolutely! ;D thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. I didn't know you can use `return` statement even when method returns `Unit`:

```
fun handle(cmd: Command) {
  return when(cmd) {
    is FirstCommand -> //whatever     
  }
}
```

Now, code above does not compile because `when` needs all the branches. Just what I wanted.

Comment: You lost the return type in the process though (probably a typo)

Comment: @Zoe Actually I'm returning "void" (Unit)

Comment: You had `Any` as the return type in the question though, just wanted to make sure it wasn't a typo :)

Comment: @Zoe It was just for clarify that, if there is a return type, compiler cmplains. But my "real" code returns Unit. Thanks anyway